# Multiple choice list to PHP request

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have this datatable which gets its data from a server. The problem now is that the database contains a bit more data than i first imagined it would. So for keeping the browser from loading all entries i've created a multiple select list that I will use for only pulling out the essential information.

The input from this list is then matched with what's in the database. The result of that is then stored in $results as can be seen below.

The problem here is that i have no idea how to get the input data, especially if its multiple choice, to go in to the last mysql query which then go into $results.

Later on I use $results for pushing out data to a table. Though as i said it gets a bit crowded in the table when i load all my data into $results.

Everything else is working properly and I get my scopeIDs in my multiple select list.

So, how do I get my selected option/s to go in to

```
<?php   
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableID LIKE (/*some cool way of putting the input here*/)";
        ?>
```

Complete Code for the task:

```
///Connection parameters above///
    $multiplechoice = mysql_query("SELECT scopeId FROM tableID");
            $storeArray = array();
            print"<select multiple name=\"scopeValues\" id=\"scopeIdchoice\">";
            while ($rowchoice = mysql_fetch_array($multiplechoice, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $storeArray =  $rowchoice['scopeId'];  
    print"<option id='".strtolower($storeArray)."'>";
    print $storeArray;
    print"</option>";

    }

    <?php   
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableID LIKE (/*some cool way of putting the input here*/)";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is more than one value associated with a input now you need to tell the server to store all values in a array (notice the brackets):

```
name=\"scopeValues[]\"
```

Then you implode the array and run the SQL. I'll assume that you're POSTing the form data:

```
$scopeValues = implode(',', $_POST['scopeValues']);
// … remember to sanitize $scopeValues before the query
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableID WHERE scopeId IN ($scopeValues) )";
```

Make sure to sanitize all the values in `$scopeValues` before interpolating them into the query to protect against SQL Injection. A more secure way would be not to use ext/mysql (it's deprecated anyway) and use PDO or ext/mysqli and use prepared statements.

(Are the IDs strings?)

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the select to `scopeValues[]`.
From the select you will get an array of values in the `$_POST` array. You might pass that as a list of values to the SQL query like below. You need to adopt the `xx_thefield_xx`to the proper column name and of course need to do checks against SQL-injection, which are missing for better reading over here.

```
<?php   
    $scopeVals = $_POST['scopeValues[]'];
    // … remember to sanitize $scopeVals before the next step
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableID where xx_thefield_xx in ('" .
           implode("','", $scopeVals) . "');";
?>
```

Comment: This information is from a drop down box or do you assume they are intercepting the data with a sniffer and changing it? (I do that kind of testing sometimes)

Comment: Everything which goes from a POST to the database can be frauded.

Comment: @UselessIntern its not about sniffing or intercepting. I can create an artificial post-request to the server which alters the SQL statement in a way, that, for instance, it populates the dropdown box with user id and passwords from an arbitrary table out of the database. In the above example, I only need to post a value like `42'); (SELECT * from information_scheme. .... where '' in (' ` and your almost done.

Comment: @UselessIntern You don't even need a "sniffer" for that. Just load a page with a `<select>` and right-click it. Than, click "Inspect Element" and change the `<select>` to an `<input type="text">`. Voilà, you can type in whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you knew this, but PHP is executed on the server. Requesting your pages goes as follows:

1. A browser sends a request to your server;
2. The server executes the PHP;
3. The server sends the output to the browser;
4. The browser renders the HTML.

This poses a problem: if you change your selection (which happens in the browser), the PHP has already been executed. It can't magically change its output that got sent to the browser. So to refresh the result, you should make a form and POST the input to the same page, which would check if data had been posted, if it had, output only the selected data, if it hadn't, show everything. If you want to make it a bit more complicated (but more usable too), you could use AJAX to retrieve the results of the select query.

The other answers covered the form already, the AJAX way would be like this:

- Have a separate page which SELECTs the data using the POSTed input to filter.
- Make an AJAX request (on the page that displays the data) every time the `<select>` changes.

(Maybe this answer is totally useless to you because you already knew PHP is server-side.)